# Recover a deleted row in Sequel Pro

Tags: mysql

I accidentally deleted a row from my database with PHP execution.

Now I use Sequel Pro to administrate the database. Is there a way that I can see deleted rows from history and cancel deletion ?

Comment: "Now I use Sequel Pro to administrate the database. Is there a way that I can see deleted rows from history and cancel deletion ?" Nope you need to recover from a backup or if binary log is enabled on your MySQL which i doubt you can recover the deleted record.

Comment: Let this be a lesson to not mess around with production database.

Comment: Thank god it wasn't a production database. Just a local one ;) anyway thanks for the helps. I'm still new to this